# One SSL page assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl

I have a problems with SSL. I need only one page with SSL, but some of assets don't change protocol on https and browser show warning.
Some fonts, svg-icons and one bg-image still with http.

For assets I use Proc in env config.

```
  config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request = nil, *_|
    if request && request.ssl?
      "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}"
    else
      'http://www.mybrandnew.com'
    end
  }
```

Anybody have this problem?

P.S: for partial SSL I already use ssl_requirement

Comment: Are the "bad" assets, ones  that are referenced from css ?

Comment: For example:
 background: url(image_path("flags_large.png")) no-repeat

Comment: Are your assets on a different host to the app (ie why use asset host at all)?

Comment: assets and app on one host.

Comment: In that case if you don't have an asset host at all the browser should use the protocol of the request automatically

Comment: all bad assets from .sass files.